# Link an li>a by href element

Tags: php, selenium, behat, mink

I have a question, so I want to press on the  element who contains a specified href.My html is:

```
<ul class="nav">
   <li>
       <a href="#/basket">
```

I tried like this :

```
Then  I hover on the element "nav li a.href=#/basket"
Then  I wait 5 seconds
Then  I should see "List"
```

My feature is :

```
/**
 * @Then /^I hover on the element "([^"]*)"$/
 */
public function iHoverOnTheElement($link){
    $session = $this->getSession(); // get the mink session
    $element = $session->getPage()->find('css', $link); // runs the actual query and returns the element
    // ok, let's hover it
    $element->clickLink($link);
}
```

But I get the error : "Expected selector, but found ".
Help me please. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

So I resolved the problem by changing my feature like this :

```
$element = $this->getSession()->getPage()->find('xpath', '//a[text()="Basket"]');
$element->click();
```